# Jupyter Notebook Kernel busy all the time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have instaled anaconda and python works fine in Sypder , IPython etc . However I am not able to run python notebook.

Kernel gets created , it also connects but it shows the dark circle busy symbol throughout . There is no problem with the firewall or antivirus .
I have tried by disabling both .

I am also not able to open python terminal from notebook there is some powershell error.

Can anyone suggest something ?

Edit 1 : Added the snapshot and the log

Log Anaconda Prompt :

```
(base) C:\Users\Project>jupyter notebook
[I 13:11:26.561 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\Project\A
naconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 13:11:26.561 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Projec
t\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 13:11:26.569 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Pr
oject
[I 13:11:26.570 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 13:11:26.570 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=28e7406ee648d631648f9b
8c53e1f3027f5eb30516ccf15f
[I 13:11:26.571 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all
 kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:11:26.768 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Project/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3064-o
pen.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=28e7406ee648d631648f9b8c53e1f3027f5eb30516c
cf15f
[I 13:11:56.237 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 13:12:02.401 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 55d8fb5e-2fe7-4d4b-a1d3-a11b0b7e7e7
d
[I 13:12:05.242 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 55d8fb5e-2fe7-
4d4b-a1d3-a11b0b7e7e7d
```

And the image where kernel is always busy

[kernel busy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oai75.png)

Comment: What is your version of ipykernel?

Comment: did you try executing jupyter in a seperate [conda environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)?

Comment: Could you resolve the error?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth its 5.1.0 , I have actually installed anaconda . I also tried 4. versions as welll no help

Comment: @ohlr yes I tried seperate environment also with python version 2.7 as well .

Comment: There is no change the kernel always remains busy irrespective of the browser as well. I have been trying to fix this since three days , almost spend 20 hrs in finding solutions

Comment: pip install 'ipykernel<5.0.0' . Try this as a temporary workaround.

Comment: As I already told you i tried on older versions , it does not work . However if I follow your exact syntax even then it does not work .

Comment: Can you provide a log of your terminal output?

Comment: Is this problem specific to conda? Have you tried a different virtualenv ?

Comment: I tried creating new environment as well ,suceess at all . I dont  think the problem is specific to conda as I also tried installing python 3.7 seperate and then installing jupyter notebook , it always keeps kernel busy , however kernel gets connected .

Comment: @ohlr do you mean the the logs in the prompt ?

Comment: interesting thing all other tools are working fine like spyder etc. the problem is specific to jupyter notebook

Comment: just any logs you have, terminal output etc. - you say something about powershell error - hand us some traces - otherwise it's hard to see what's going on

Comment: @ohlr I have edited the question with the image and the logs nothing seems going wrong to me .. yet the kernel shows busy

Comment: Do you have anaconda in your bashrc? I.e can you call it without running 'source anaconda/bin/activate'? If so please remove it

Comment: Well I am using windows 7 .  Does that still apply ?

Comment: yes, maybe the commands are different but the idea is the same.. have a look at [point 8](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)

Comment: also you could try to pip install, jupyter within your conda environment.. hoping that it makes a difference

Comment: and like I said earlyer, don't do stuff in the (base) environment.. instead make a new env for each project.

Comment: Does it happen when you create a new notebook/ When you open an already existing notebook or both the times? Also is there a ipynb_checkpoints folder created when you open the notebook in a new directory?

Comment: I have tried creating new conda  enviroments . no difference. Spyder Ipython shell and other things work perfectly fine . Only problem with jupyter notebook .  I am running it in chrome as my IE version is still 8 does that affect by any chance ?

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same issue, I tried a lot of different stuff but nothing seemed to help me out. Ultimately, a `Kernel Restart` instead of `Kernel Interrupt` helped me out! The kernel restarted and I was able to run the kernels as usual.

I think this is just a workaround if someone finds the real solution please do let us know!

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue because I started it as below

jupyter notebook --gateway-url=http://my-domain.com:8888

but I remove geteway-url param then the issue was gone

I know that you didn't make this very same mistake like me but I hope this gives you some clues