# Jupyter Notebook is not responding in GCP (google cloud platform)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter notebook kernel is showing busy all the time, even though I restarted the notebook instance. Anyone faced this problem or anyone know the solution?

[image]

Comment: Could you give a little more context about where it runs (compute engine) etc.?

Comment: Might help you with some suggestions: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669796/jupyter-notebook-kernel-busy-all-the-time]

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem but there is no solution.

Comment: Could you provide further details on the notebook (e.g. configuration, how you created it, what it is running,...)?